# A version of as.character that does not round integers

Tags: r

base::as.character() rounds integers with decimal places:

```
>as.character(5.00)
>"5"
```

So the two zeros after the decimal place are lost, whereas

```
>as.character(5.01)
>"5.01"
```

Keeps the two numbers. Although I can understand whilst dropping the zeros is sensible, I'm interested in where unnecessary digits have been used, so I'd like to keep everything. What I really want is something like:

```
>as.character.f(c(5, 5.0, 5.00))
>"5"  "5.0"  "5.00"
```

Comment: Not sure of the usage of this feature. But if in case you are interested in alternative approach then this might help you - `sprintf("%.2f", c(5, 5.0, 5.00))` or
`formatC(c(5, 5.0, 5.00), 2, format = "f")`

Comment: I was wondering how could you get a variable to store values as `5.0, 5.0, 5.00`? I can understand you can mention as `hard-coded` if so they why not declare of type `character` itself at the `1st` place.

Comment: This is technically not correct, but well if you want one you will receive an answer

Comment: @MKR's point is excellent. Either you have direct input, in which case just take the input as character instead of a number; or you have numeric data in which case you can't know the original accuracy without an additional variable.

Comment: The original inputs were characters (my apologies), so the function below works.
    decimalplaces <- function(x) {
       if(any(str_detect(pattern='\\.', string=x))==T){ #
         res = nchar(str_split(x, pattern = '\\.', simplify = T)[,2])
       }
       if(any(str_detect(pattern='\\.', string=x))==F){ # no decimal places
         res = rep(0, length(x))
       }
       return(res)
     }

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use more of a for-loop to be able to reproduce what you want:

```
mapply(format,c(5,5.0,5.00),nsmall=c(0,1,2))
[1] "5"   "5.0"  "5.00"
```

Comment: This requires knowing the number of zeroes though, since `mapply(format, rep(5, 3), nsmall = c(0, 1, 2))` will produce exactly the same result.

Comment: Sure. There is no way to reproduce whatever OP needs unless it is hardcoded. Nothing more. Since even writting 5.00 in the console will output 5