# R: as.character removes trailing zeros of numbers. How to avoid

Tags: r, dplyr, character

I have

```
kappa<-c(0.10, NA, 0.0740)
```

When I do

```
kappa %>% replace(is.na(.), "")
```

I get

```
> kappa %>% replace(is.na(.), "")
[1] "0.1"   ""      "0.074"
```

The same when I do

```
> as.character(kappa)
[1] "0.1"   NA      "0.074"
```

How can I avoid (in the `remove()` case) the removal of the trailing zero?
I would like to result to the following vector

```
"0.10", NA, "0.0740"
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187439/a-version-of-as-character-that-does-not-round-integers

Comment: If you load 0.10 as a number in R, it will save the value and not the representation, ie it will be 0.1. To load "0.10", load it in as character data with `c("0.10", NA, "0.0740")`

Comment: ECII, how are you (in practice) instantiating your data? Is it literally you typing something in, or is it a column from (say) `read.csv` or similar programmatic data import? If the former, then JonSpring's comment is appropriate, though we all know that this means you cannot do "number"-like things on them without a bit of extra work. Also, what is your purpose for saving the trailing zeroes? Perhaps you can read in as `character`, preserve that, then `as.numeric` that vector into another vector for number-like ops. Idk, but ... it depends on how you get it and what you need to do with it.

Comment: I have a numeric variable that needs to be converted to character. I would like to have all the values have the same character length as they will be used to form a table for publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `format()` with a `nsmall` argument as the number of digits.

This number can be computed as the maximum of the base 10 logarithm of your numeric vector (but you obviously can enter any arbitrary value).

Here is the code:

```r
kappa = c(0.10, NA, 0.0740)
n_digits = max(abs(log(kappa)), na.rm=TRUE)
format(kappa, nsmall=n_digits)
#> [1] "0.100" "   NA" "0.074"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>